# Invoking a Java web service from JavaScript: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in Chrome

Tags: javascript, web-services

I am trying to invoke a Java web service method from JavaScript code. The web service method returns the String type, but when invoked through JavaScript it gives the following error in the Chrome console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

The web service method is as follow:

```
public String getName(){
    name="hello";
    return name;
}
```

(`name` is a class level variable.)

The JavaScript I wrote to invoke the above method of the web service is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CallService() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/TestWS/services/HelloWorld/getName",
            contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "jsonp text xml html",
            success: Success,
            error: Error
        });
    }

    function Success(data, status) {
        alert(data);
    }

    function Error(request, status, error) {
        alert(error);
    }
</script>
```

I tried googling for the error, but I couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify only a single `dataType`. Right now, you seem to have listed all possible types. Also, you specified `contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8"`, but you are not sending any data with the request. Finally, you have specified an absolute [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) potentially violating the [`same origin policy`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restriction (you cannot send cross domain [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) requests).

So after taking those remarks into account you may try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CallService() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/TestWS/services/HelloWorld/getName",
            success: Success,
            error: Error
        });
    }

    function Success(data, status) {
        alert(data);
    }

    function Error(request, status, error) {
        alert(error);
    }
</script>
```

This obviously assumes that the web service that you are trying to consume is hosted on the same domain as the page hosting your JavaScript code.

If this is not the case, you might consider using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), but for this to work you will need to modify your web service to support it.

Comment: I am running my java script and web-service in same domain (its running on same machine and using the same host, that is what i understand from same domain) but when i try to use it the way you mentioned, it Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. So i went for using JSONP.
Edit: Can you please provide some reference or way what changes I have to make in webservice to support JSONP. I am pretty new webservice.Thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't forget that the port also plays an important role. So `http://localhost:1234` and `http://localhost:4567` is not the same domain. Also as I already explained in my answer in order to use JSONP you should modify your web service so that it supports it. JSONP means that you should wrap the response in a callback. Please read more about JSONP here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, both are hosted on same port: 8080

Comment: Alright if both are hosted on the same port you don't need to use an absolute url. Just use a relative path as shown in my answer: `url: "/TestWS/services/HelloWorld/getName"`. Also make sure you have removed the `contentType` parameter from the AJAX call in which you were setting it to XML.

Comment: Many people confuse JSON and JSONP and think that they could just tell jQuery to use JSONP in order to consume some cross domain service. This is a fundamental misunderstanding. It is the REMOTE Web service that needs to support JSONP and return JSONP formatted responses for this to work. This doesn't seem to be your case though as both are hosted on the same domain.

Comment: Thanks it helped but one more issue. Now the output i receive is complete xml type:
<ns:getNameResponse xmlns:ns="http://helloService">
<ns:return>hello</ns:return>
</ns:getNameResponse>
Edit: is it the right output? Because what i expect is just the string "hello"